# Spring Cloud Data Flow Streams Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I launch Spring cloud data flow with docker-compose base on this website.

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/

I created 3 apps, Source, Processor & Sink.

I registered them on the Spring Data Flow Cloud Dashboard.

Then I created a stream with the source connecting to processor connecting to sink.

When I deployed the apps, and opened http://localhost:9393/streams/logs/{name-of-stream},

I get the following error,

```
{
logs: {
testdir-stream.sender1-v3: "Error: Unable to access jarfile /testdir/data-sender-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ",
testdir-stream.sink1-v3: "Error: Unable to access jarfile /testdir/data-sink-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ",
testdir-stream.processor1-v3: "Error: Unable to access jarfile /testdir/data-processor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "
}
}
```

Apparently, the Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) server cannot access(or executing it or something?) the jarfile. I have chmod +x the entire testdir folder in the docker container such that the permissions is 'drwxr-xrwx'.

However, SCDF is still unable to access the jar. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

EDIT

I am running `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml -f ./docker-compose-prometheus.yml up`

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.25
    container_name: dataflow-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dataflow
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
    expose:
      - 3306

  kafka-0:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1
    container_name: dataflow-kafka-0
    expose:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-0
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1
    container_name: dataflow-kafka-1
    expose:
      - "9093"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9093
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-1
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1
    container_name: dataflow-kafka-zookeeper
    expose:
      - "2181"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181

  dataflow-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    volumes:
      - 'C:\Users\Desmond\Desktop\Desmond\Project\springcloud:/root/apps'
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9093
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9093
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper:2181
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper:2181
      - spring.cloud.skipper.client.serverUri=http://skipper-server:7577/api
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    depends_on:
      - kafka-0
      - kafka-1
    entrypoint: "./wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -- java -jar /maven/spring-cloud-dataflow-server.jar"

  app-import:
    image: springcloud/openjdk:2.0.0.RELEASE
    container_name: dataflow-app-import
    depends_on:
      - dataflow-server
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "
        ./wait-for-it.sh -t 180 dataflow-server:9393;
        wget -qO- 'http://dataflow-server:9393/apps' --post-data='uri=${STREAM_APPS_URI:-https://dataflow.spring.io/kafka-maven-latest&force=true}';
        echo 'Stream apps imported'
        wget -qO- 'http://dataflow-server:9393/apps' --post-data='uri=${TASK_APPS_URI:-https://dataflow.spring.io/task-maven-latest&force=true}';
        echo 'Task apps imported'"
  skipper-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:${SKIPPER_VERSION:?SKIPPER_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: skipper
    ports:
      - "7577:7577"
      - "9000-9010:9000-9010"
      - "20000-20105:20000-20105"
    environment:
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_PORTRANGE_LOW=20000
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_PORTRANGE_HIGH=20100
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    entrypoint: "./wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -- java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /spring-cloud-skipper-server.jar"
```

docker-compose-prometheus.yml

```
version: '3'

# Extends the default docker-compose.yml with Prometheus/Grafana monitoring configuration
# Usage: docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml -f ./docker-compose-prometheus.yml up
services:

  dataflow-server:
    environment:
      - |
        SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON=
        {
          "spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties":{
             "task.management.metrics.export.prometheus":{
                "enabled":true,
                "rsocket.enabled":true,
                "rsocket.host":"prometheus-rsocket-proxy",
                "rsocket.port":7001
             },
             "stream.management.metrics.export.prometheus":{
                "enabled":true,
                "rsocket.enabled":true,
                "rsocket.host":"prometheus-rsocket-proxy",
                "rsocket.port":7001
             }
          },
          "spring.cloud.dataflow.grafana-info.url":"http://localhost:3000"
        }

  prometheus-rsocket-proxy:
    image: micrometermetrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy:0.8.0
    container_name: prometheus-rsocket-proxy
    expose:
      - '9096'
      - '7001'
      - '8081'
    ports:
      - '9096:9096'
      - '7001:7001'
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      - server.port=9096

  grafana:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-grafana-prometheus:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set! Use 'export DATAFLOW_VERSION=local-server-image-tag'}
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  prometheus:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-prometheus-local:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:?DATAFLOW_VERSION is not set! Use 'export DATAFLOW_VERSION=local-server-image-tag'}
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-sender</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>data-sender</name>
    <description>Test Proj</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <mockito-junit-jupiter.version>2.19.0</mockito-junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- prometheus-rsocket monitoring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi, Are the apps successfully deployed by SCDF? what do you see as the stream deployment status? I want to understand if the problem is with accessing JAR files themselves or something else.

Comment: Hi, Stream Deployement Status is the orange colour failed "1 or more of the apps does not have even a single instance deployed". Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Are you running this on a macos? If so worth to check that your docker vm has enough resources and all the services in a compose file got starter fine.

Comment: I am running this on windows. I have added docker-compose.yml and docker-compose-prometheus.yml

Comment: Or if you registered these apps as `file:` in your host, it needs to be in a volume location defined in a compose file so that all containers can access via same paths.

Comment: Hi yes the jar files are in volume location. The container is able to see the jar file. I am also able to java -jar the jar in the container. However, spring-cloud-data-flow stream is unable to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing custom applications from your local machine, you need to configure both the `dataflow-server` and the `skipper-skipper` Docker containers to access to your local file system. You have already mounted the source folder to `dataflow-server` but you need to do the same with the `skipper-server` definition like this:

```
  skipper-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:${SKIPPER_VERSION:?SKIPPER_VERSION is not set!}
    container_name: skipper
    volumes:
      - 'C:\Users\Desmond\Desktop\Desmond\Project\springcloud:/root/apps'
     ...
```

We will clarify this in our documentation [#128](https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io/issues/128)

---

Two additional points regarding `prometheus-rsocket` monitoring:

- Since you are using the new `prometheus-rsocket` configuration you will need to import the `Einstein-BUILD-SNAPSHOT-stream-applications-kafka-maven` app starters instead of `kafka-maven-latest`. You can do this by setting the following property before starting docker-compose:

  `export STREAM_APPS_URI=https://dataflow.spring.io/Einstein-BUILD-SNAPSHOT-stream-applications-kafka-maven`

  The SR4 app starter release is expected very soon, but until then you need to use the BUILD-SNAPSHOT to leverage the prometheus metrics.
- Can you please share how you have implemented your custom apps? Do they contain the following dependencies?

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      ...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-starters-core-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    ....
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    ...
  </repositories>
```

If your apps's parent POM is `org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:app-starters-build:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` above dependencies are already injected. Otherwise you have to add them manually.

UPDATE -- adding a simple pom configuration to enable `prometheus-rsocket` metrics:

```
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>-->
        <prometheus-rsocket-spring.version>0.8.0</prometheus-rsocket-spring.version>
    </properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus-rsocket-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus-rsocket-spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, Regarding the first point, I have mounted the source folder to skipper-server and it now works.

Comment: For the 2nd points, I have added the dependency as suggested. I am getting this error [ERROR]   The project org.dso.info.io:data-sender:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Desmond\Desktop\Desmond\Project\springcloud\data-sender\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:app-starters-micrometer-common:jar is missing. @ line 100, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.micrometer.prometheus:prometheus-rsocket-spring:jar is missing. @ line 108, column 15. How can i solve this? thanks

Comment: Added my pom.xml for your reference

Comment: Can you try to add the `org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:app-starters-core-dependencies:2.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` to your dependecyManagement definition and likely the Spring snapshot maven repo. I've updated the pom snipped in my response.

Comment: @Desmond I've just added a simpler pom configuration, that doesn't require snapshot dependencies on app-starter-core. I've used the second one for this task demo app: https://github.com/tzolov/task-demo-metrics/blob/prometheus-rsocket-proxy/pom.xml
(Note that the you do NOT need Boot 2.2.0.M5 and Hoxton.M2 as used in the demo. Boot 2.1.6 and Greenwich.SR2 are fine )

Comment: Hi thanks! there are no errors now and i can build my custom jar

Comment: Hi would you be able to provide a sample stream demo app that works with grafana and promethues? I tried the task demo metrics but it uses influx.

Comment: Actually the `prometheus-rsocket-proxy` branch of the task demo app shows how to use the prometheus/grafana with tasks. 
Mind that for Stream apps you may still need the `<artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>` in order to use the OOTB grafana stream dashboards. I will write sample stream app from scratch to illustrate the approach.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Awaiting the sample stream app :)

Comment: Hi, may I know if the sample stream app would be up? Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi @Desmond, i've put here demo source, processor and sink apps (using the imperative programming model) for rabbit binder that include all required dependencies to use SCDF Prometheus-RSocket-Proxy configuration: 
https://github.com/tzolov/demo-prometheus-proxy-stream-app
Note that some of the dependencies are still BS, but are very close to release (this week hopefully). Once released you won't need the POM repository section.

Answer (score 0):

I believe container configs are wrong for skipper server as that's the one running those containers if `local` setup is used. It should work if same volume is used in skipper as it's now done with dataflow server.

For getting those logs, dataflow simply requests those from a skipper and error originates from there.